# How to set up roo to use derby client driver with DBRE addon?

Tags: derby, spring-roo

How can one set up roo so that it uses derby client driver to reverse engineer existing database objects?

Answer (score 2):

First, try DBRE command and see what errors do you get. Command:
`> database reverse engineering --schema <your_schema_name> --package ~.domain`

Then you will see what are the errors...

I needed to install addons for Derby like this:

`> addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.springframework.roo.wrapping.derby`
`> addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.springframework.roo.wrapping.derbyclient`

Then called:
`> persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database DERBY`

Then you would probably need to change your database.properties file in your project to contain correct location of your database. Mine settings are:

`// database.password=`
`// database.url=jdbc\:derby\:roo_crm;`
`// database.username=`
`// database.driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`

Again, different database (other than Derby) might have another driver and database.url.

Then I was able to generate code using DBRE Spring Roo feature like this:

`> database reverse engineer --schema APP --package ~.domain`

Then I have opened my project in springroo tool suite and I was able to see code in java and aspectJ.

Comment: Since the question specifically mentioned "Derby client driver", the database.url field might need to be more like "database.url=jdbc:derby://my-machine:1527/roo_crm", as the url format for the client driver is slightly different than the url format for the embedded driver.